# Set created from Arrays.asList storing duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, set

I used a structure like the following to get unique elements from an array of objects.

```
dataList.put(column, new LinkedList<Object>(new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()))));
```

The array from entry.getValue() is a 100 element array containing values from 1 to 99, with 1 being repeated twice.

The documentation says that `Arrays.asList(arr[])` method returns a fixed-length list of the same length as the array.

I have observed that the set created also contains the duplicate values given by the original array.

Please explain this behaviour.

**More details.**

I have also tried using `set.addAll(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue());` , where set is a HashSet and got the same results.

The array returned by entry.getValue() is an array of type java.lang.Short

Comment: Where is the `Set` here?

Comment: You need a `Set` but you don't have one.

Neither a `LinkedList`, `Àrrays.asList()` or an array do anything to remove duplicates.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to include the set.

Comment: What is the type returned by `entry.getValue()`?

Comment: It is an Array of Objects.

Comment: So it returns `Object[]`. What type are the objects? (@Happy - that's where I'm going)

Comment: Did you override equals and hashCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the above code fragment with arrays of various data types I found that arrays of primitive types are stored as a single array object, whereas arrays of Java Classes like String, Integer, Float etc. are stored as a collection of their elements.

In my case I had an array of int[] passed into the HashSet as a List, which was taken as a single Object and no filtering out of duplicate elements was done. When the array contained Integer objects, the HashSet could filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you didn't override `equals()` in the class of the objects in the array returned by `entry.getValue()`. And especially since you are using a `HashSet`, you should override `hashCode()` too, so that it "agrees" with `equals()`, as per the [javadoc of `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

If you don't override `equals()`, each instance will not be `equal()` to any other instance despite its "value" being the same, because that's the default implementation of `equals()`, so the `Set` will see both "1" objects as "different".

Comment: It is an array of Objects because it is supposed to hold integers, dates and strings, the standard java classes. They override hashCode and equals by default, right?

Comment: Right. Maybe you have a String `"1"` and an Integer `1`?

Comment: @njkb How about showing some more codes, specially the one where you are populating the list, or array.

Comment: @Bohemian I am sure that all the elements are of the same type. Let me try to find the original array and update it.

Comment: All the elements in the array are of type primitive int.

Comment: @njkb Do you mean, you have array of type `int[]`, and you are passing it to `Arrays.asList()` method? That will create a `List<int[]>` with a single element, and not `List<Integer>` with 100 elements.

Comment: But the size of the set created is 100. I have verified using set.addAll(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()); and using debug mode in eclipse, found the size of set to be 100.

Comment: @njkb If the array is of type `int[]`, then the size of the `set` will be `1`. It can't be anything else, not unless you have some other code that you haven't shown.

Comment: I am very sorry. Turns out it was an array of java.lang.Short after all.

Comment: @njkb Try printing the content of the `Set` and see what you get.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 1]

Comment: @njkb That is simply not happening. You need to show us some more code. In fact, think of what all code are related, post it here. Are you by any chance using a different `Set`?